How much weight is reasonable to carry for weeks-long trip
I'm planning a weeks-long cycling trip through Mexico, and I'm currently buying some necessary gear, like repair kit, first aid kit, camping equipment, etc. However, I'm not sure about the weight limit I should carry on such a trip.
I'll be taking it slow, but I also don't want to tire myself out by carrying too much.

Have you done any overnight trips yet?   Rather than jump straight to a weeks-long tour, try doing an out-and-back the next day.  Any item you don't need, don't take next time.

Or test yourself and build up for longer rides by loading your bicycle with how much weight you think you will need, like doing supermarket runs by bike.

I don't think there's a single answer. How much 'luxury' do you want? The last time I went on a 3 week cycling trip, we carried maybe 30 kg between the two of us, including a large tent, cooking equipment and camp chairs ;-) OTOH I saw some minimalist bike packers with a single bag that would probably be around 8 kg. this didn't look like a vacation to me though.

Other things to consider are how much food you need to take with you; are there any shops where you are going? How much water?

There is no answer to this question. The weight limit is defined only by your physical and mental abilities. The more prepared you are physically, the more you can carry. The more prepared you are mentally, the less you can carry.

If you weren't aware of this site, https://bikepacking.com is another place to look for relevant information

Totally depends.
Some people achieve a base weight as low as 4.5kg, others carry up to 40kg of stuff.
Personally I’ve usually ended up around 10kg in two 20l rear panniers with the tent on top of the rear rack.
Weight is important. Don’t bring stuff you could easily do without. I’ve seen people bring full sized pliers, hammer, rolls of duct tape, heavy 3 person tents (>4kg), a change of clothes for every day, bottle of wine etc. etc.
It can quickly add up to more than 20kg which will make ascends a chore and carrying the fully loaded bike will be very difficult.
When you bring a lot of stuff you also need more bags/panniers and a sturdier, heavier bike.
Make a pack list. Weigh every item. For every item evaluate if you really need/want it or if there is a lighter option.
Edit: Where I’d err on the side of caution and comfort is warmth of clothes and quilt/sleeping bag. Don’t bring your 10°C comfort summer sleeping bag just because it’s 200g lighter than your winter sleeping bag if you expect temperatures to go down to 0°C. Don’t hesitate too much to bring your 400g down puffy if you expect temperatures to be cold at camp. Same for water and food. Especially if you are in remote areas and can’t just ride to the next hotel if the night gets too cold or to a supermarket if you run out of water/food.

Summarizing the comments into a single answer...
The goal is to carry only what you will use and nothing more.
It sounds simple but it requires factoring in the resources you will find along the way and requires guessing at the future. If you can find and talk to people who have already traveled the road you will be traveling it will help.
Your abilities determine how much you can carry. Without some kind of understanding what you have done - how much you have carried how far - it's not possible to guess what you can do.
If this is a new adventure for you there are ways to experiment and determine what your abilities are.

Don't assume that you are ready for a "weeks long trip"
Take some short trips and monitor what you carry, how you carry it, how far you go, and how you feel when you are done.
Build up to medium trips and experiment with equipment. It's easier to pack light in warm weather than cold weather.

If riding for weeks long is something you do regularly and you are comfortable with the distance involved, then include gear on your rides and experiment with comfort level.
Happy travels - stay safe!
